# How to make UISearchBar transparent with white text and placeholder

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am using UISearchController extension to setup appearance of my search bar.

I tried insert empty images and other solutions, but still no luck.

Also I can't change search bar text and placeholder to white. It's every-time black and gray correspondently.

[image]

There is my extension code:

```
extension UISearchController {
    func setStackedDefaultAppearance() {

        self.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

        self.searchBar.setImage(UIImage(named: "search"), for: .search, state: .normal)

        let searchBar = self.searchBar
        searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

        searchBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
        searchBar.scopeBarBackgroundImage = UIImage()

        if let textfield = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {

            if let backgroundview = textfield.subviews.first {

                backgroundview.backgroundColor = UIColor.stackedStatusBarBlue

                backgroundview.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
                backgroundview.clipsToBounds = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve that my search bar's color will be the same as navigation bar color:

[image]

Kind of transparent background color with no borders.

Comment: check this one https://gist.github.com/wavecos/970a0e0bad82d258c22c#gistcomment-2077845

Comment: thanks clear background color seems works for me, but looks like this method shift search bar a bit

Comment: changing text color does not work (